# Selenium grid with appium android and protractor configuration

Tags: android, angular, selenium, protractor, angular-cli

I've got a selenium grid with chrome, firefox and android node running

[image]

and I have this protractor configuration within an angular cli project:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const {SpecReporter} = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var screenshotReporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'android',
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'platformVersion': '7.1.1',
    'deviceName': 'Nexus 5'
  }],
  // directConnect: true,
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () {
    }
  },

  beforeLaunch: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      screenshotReporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({spec: {displayStacktrace: true}}));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(screenshotReporter);
  },

  afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      screenshotReporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    })
  }
};
```

When I launch my ng e2e task, tests  are running fine on firefox and chrome node. However, I've got this error coming from the android capability:

```
WebDriverError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The desired capabilities must include either an app, appPackage or browserName
...
```

If I get it right the android webdriver asks me to include a browserName although I already provide it one. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try removing  `'deviceName': 'Nexus 5'` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

the andriod capability in your protractor config file will failed to get any matched node for you. Because you use one wrong name and one wrong value in capability.

you use 'platformVersion', but on selenium gird is 'version'. 
you set 'deviceName' to 'Nexus 5', but on selenium gird is 'nexus_5_7.1.1'

please change 'platformVersion' to 'version' and correct 'Nexus 5' to 'nexus_5_7.1.1' in your protractor config file, then try again.

My last concern is on your selenium grid the browserName is 'android', I'm not sure testing can open the browser.

In most case, we install Chrome on andriod device and set browserName to 'Chrome' when register device to selenium grid and in protractor config file.

I indeed not know 'andriod' represents which browser, the build-in browser bind with andriod OS?